# Boot hangs on crc32c-intel since kernel 4.19.94

Tags: boot, kernel

Since I put kernel 4.19.94 or any 5.4.* I cannot access my system. This doesn't happen with 4.19.93. I need to use a livesystem to restore a Timeshift backup, but any attempt to install a newer kernel results in the same hanging when the computer is booting.

--edit/-- Might be of interest : I'm running an AMD-system MSI X470 + Ryzen 2700X - 32Gb Adata RAM - System is on M.2 (512 Gb), Home (1 Gb) is separate disk/partition. --/edit--

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Karel :)

Answer (score 0):

I gave up. I finished by a complete reinstall. 2x in fact, the first di not boot at all, secvond attempt worked after a round trip to partitioning the disk again. Remove all partitions and put them back worked a charm. Next few days trying to grab all soft that was added on the original setup.

Cheers